# highstock.js date ranges less then a hour don't work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using hightstocks.js I can't seem to get any date ranges less then a hour to work. Lets say I want to select 30 minutes of data, the chart goes blank. My data  is in 1 minute increments so I should be able to do this. I would like to do 15 minute ranges and 30 minutes ranges. If I do any ranges greater then a hour the chart works fine.

here is a example of my data.

```
[1508459821000, 0.000244, 0.000244, 0.00024399, 0.00024399],
[1508459882000, 0.0002441, 0.0002442, 0.000244, 0.000244],
[1508459942000, 0.0002442, 0.0002442, 0.0002442, 0.0002442],
[1508460061000, 0.0002442, 0.0002442, 0.0002442, 0.0002442],
[1508460122000, 0.00024492, 0.00024494, 0.0002442, 0.00024],
```

Example of my code

```
  // 
   datas = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2011, 9, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null]]); 
   create the chart
        Highcharts.stockChart('chart', {
            chart: {
                type: 'candlestick',
                zoomType: 'x'
            },

            navigator: {
                adaptToUpdatedData: true,
                series: {
                    data: data
                }
            },

            scrollbar: {
                liveRedraw: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [
                    {
                        type: 'minute',
                        count: 15,
                        text: '15m'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'minute',
                        count: 30,
                        text: '30m'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'hour',
                        count: 1,
                        text: '1h'
                    }],
                    inputEnabled: false, // it supports only days
                    selected: 4 // all

            },

            xAxis: {
                events: {
                    afterSetExtremes: afterSetExtremes
                },
            },

            yAxis: {

                labels: {

                    color: '#fffff',

                    formatter: function () {
                        return Number(this.value).toFixed(8);
                    }
                },

                floor: 0
            },



            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: "{point.y:.8f} BTC"
            },


            series: [{
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }]
        });
```

Comment: can you please create a demo?

Comment: You could do it like `count: 60, text: '1h'`

Comment: `My data is in 1 minute increments` - well, 60 or 61, and one 119 second increments to be accurate :p

Answer (score 0):

As your data is counted in minute, you should use it as minute even if the label is `1h`

```
{
type: 'minute',
count: 60, // not 1
text: '1h'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue.

```
datas = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2011, 9, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null]]);
```

I was adding null for the end date and I used Date.UTC.  Well my server is running on MST. I just had to take off the .UTC and it started working.